Implementing static bounds checking in Rust using `typenum`
Problem statement
I have a Rust parsing library for wire-encoded buffers of bytes, and I'm trying to generate a "view" data structure, ByteSliceReader, for writing subparsers that enforces bounds checking at compile time. Since const generics don't appear to have sufficient functionality to allow this (correct me if I'm wrong), I tried using the typenum crate. However, I'm getting weird/difficult-to-understand compiler errors, so I'm looking for guidance on how to resolve them.
(I don't think I can use generic-array since subparsers need to use functions like f32::from_le_bytes which accepts a [u8; 4].)
Implementation
The data structure looks roughly like this (except that there's actually a ring buffer storing the data instead of an array):
use typenum::*;

struct ByteSliceReader<'a, const LEN: usize, Cursor> {
    buffer: &'a [u8; LEN],
    cursor: core::marker::PhantomData<Cursor>,
}

Here Cursor is intended to be a typenum-based unsigned integer that tracks how many bytes have been consumed by the subparser. It has one method to "pop" a number of bytes determined by a const generic:
impl<'a, const LEN: usize, Cursor: Unsigned> ByteSliceReader<'a, LEN, Cursor>
where
    Const<LEN>: ToUInt,
    U<LEN>: Unsigned,
{
    #[must_use]
    fn pop<const NUM: usize>(self) -> (ByteSliceReader<'a, LEN, Sum<Cursor, U<NUM>>>, [u8; NUM])
    where
        Const<NUM>: ToUInt,
        Cursor: core::ops::Add<U<NUM>>,
        Sum<Cursor, U<NUM>>: IsLessOrEqual<U<LEN>>,
    {
        let mut byte_window = [0; NUM];
        for (i, byte) in byte_window.iter_mut().enumerate() {
            *byte = self.buffer[Cursor::to_usize() + i];
        }

        (
            ByteSliceReader::<LEN, _> {
                buffer: self.buffer,
                cursor: core::marker::PhantomData,
            },
            byte_window,
        )
    }
}

This all compiles fine. But when I try to use it in this example helper function (intended to extract and parse some bytes), it doesn't compile:
fn get_serial_and_part_num<const LEN: usize, Cursor>(
    reader: ByteSliceReader<'_, LEN, Cursor>,
) -> (ByteSliceReader<'_, LEN, Sum<Sum<Cursor, U1>, U1>>, (u8, u8))
where
    Cursor: Unsigned,
    Cursor: core::ops::Add<U1>,
    Sum<Cursor, U1>: core::ops::Add<U1> + Unsigned,
    Const<LEN>: ToUInt,
    U<LEN>: Unsigned,
{
    let (reader, serial_num) = reader.pop::<1>();
    let (reader, part_num) = reader.pop::<1>();
    (reader, (serial_num[0], part_num[0]))
}

Error
error[E0599]: the method `pop` exists for struct `ByteSliceReader<'_, LEN, Cursor>`, but its trait bounds were not satisfied
   --> fsw/sensors/ring_parser.rs:528:43
    |
483 |     struct ByteSliceReader<'a, const LEN: usize, Cursor> {
    |     ---------------------------------------------------- method `pop` not found for this struct
...
528 |         let (reader, serial_num) = reader.pop::<1>();
    |                                           ^^^ method cannot be called on `ByteSliceReader<'_, LEN, Cursor>` due to unsatisfied trait bounds
    |
    = note: the following trait bounds were not satisfied:
            `Cursor: Add<<typenum::Const<_> as typenum::ToUInt>::Output>`
help: consider restricting the type parameter to satisfy the trait bound
    |
526 |         U<LEN>: Unsigned, Cursor: Add<<typenum::Const<_> as typenum::ToUInt>::Output>
    |                         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

The compiler's suggestion contains a _, which I interpret as 1, but applying it doesn't help. I've tried various permutations of bounds and gotten various similar errors. Is there some way to achieve what I want?

generic-array can convert to [T; N].

The immediate problem is that you need to tell the compiler that the Output of Const<1> as ToUInt will be U1:
    Const<1>: ToUInt<Output = U1>,

However that then leads to further unsatisfied trait bounds (namely the IsLessOrEqual ones):
    Sum<Cursor, U1>: IsLessOrEqual<U<LEN>>,
    Sum<Sum<Cursor, U1>, U1>: IsLessOrEqual<U<LEN>>,

See it on the playground.

Thanks a lot. ToUInt is implemented for Const<1> in typenum, so why is that first bound required? And do you know why the compiler errors were so unhelpful?

@JoshBurkart: You are relying upon U<1> being U1, but that is a detail of Const<1>'s ToUInt implementation that is not guaranteed to be the case; we are therefore required to constrain our function to only be applicable when that condition is met.

@JoshBurkart: The errors are unhelpful mostly because complex usages of the type system like this are a little outside the use-cases for which the rust compiler and its diagnostic outputs have been heavily stress-tested.  Generally speaking, I find it better to avoid overly complex type-level designs in favour of simpler runtime checks that are often optimised away anyway.  Only when absolutely necessary might I go searching for some complex solution involving the type system.

By all means open a diagnostic bug report on the project's issue tracker if you find error messages that need improvement.

Thanks for the additional context. The implementation of ToUInt for Const<1> seems to have type Output = U1; directly, so I'm still confused about why that bound is required?

I'm not entirely sure, but requiring the compiler to resolve trait projections like this might make the trait solver intractable?  In any event, the Rust philosophy is generally to prefer being explicit over having hidden dependencies that can become a stability hazard: so you are required to state that your code depends upon U<1> = U1 rather than continuing to compile (perhaps with unexpected results) should that happen to change upstream.
